# Subjunctive usage

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I wanted to know whether this sentence is correct:

> The author, being aware of the money to be earned by ecranizations of
>   books, helped to write the scenarios for movies based on his stories.

The 'to be earned' part sounds strange to me.
What do you think?

Comment: This is not "subjunctive". There is no subjunctive mood in English; people tend to call any verb useage they don't understand "subjunctive", because they've heard subjunctive is sposta be hard to understand. What this is is a [relative infinitive](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a15299%20%22relative%20infinitive%22); that is, a relative clause that happens to be an infinitive clause instead of a tensed clause. _The money to be earned_ means _the money that can/will/should/is gonna be earned (by `Indef`)_.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds fine.  (It's not a subjunctive.)  "Money to be earned by ..." has a reduced relative clause -- it's from "Money which is to be earned by ..." and "to be earned" is an infinitive form of the passive of "earn".